# Equivalence of geometric and algebraic definition of dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Reading the [wikipedia dot product page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_the_equivalence_of_the_definitions) I am confused by the last equation:

$A \cdot B = \sum B_i(A \cdot e_i) = \sum A_iB_i$

Specifically how is the $A \cdot e_i$ part derived? How is it substituted into that equation? Also why is $A \cdot e_i = A_i$  How is this equation related to the previous equation: $A \cdot B = A_B \|B\|$ ?

Comment: presumably, $e_i$ is the vector $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ of all zeros except for a 1 at the $i$th entry. So $A\cdot e_i=A_i$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How do they get from A ⋅ B to $\sum B_i(A⋅e_i)$ ?

Comment: From $B=\sum B_ie_i$, they go $A\cdot B=A\cdot\sum B_ie_i=\sum A\cdot(B_ie_i)=\sum B_i(A\cdot e_i)$.

Comment: Ah that seems so obvious in retrospect. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At author's suggestion, my comment, as an answer:

From $B=\sum B_ie_i$, it goes $$A\cdot B=A\cdot\sum B_ie_i=\sum A\cdot(B_ie_i)=\sum B_i(A\cdot e_i)$$